# how can i add a third attribute to my user-role table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

we use the user-role based for authorization in our project. we need to add an attribute to our table (user role table),which results in the user having the role when that attribute established. for example we want to say user A in location X has a special role but same user in location Y has another roles. (using .net core)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but my problem is i want to recognize my user with third attribute, that if my user have two roles in two diffrent companies and i want to delete company A, my user role destroyed in company A but not change in company B.

Comment: I don't know if I get you right, but if I understand you correctly I would keep it simple and just have a naming convention in place and prefix all roles like this: CompA_admin, CompA_supervisor, CompB_admin etc. And then make a function that removes the user from all roles that start with CompA if the user leaves the company.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user to have multiple roles , you could add a `ApplicationRole` class that inherits `IdentityRole` , and change the relationship between `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationRole`to **one-to-many**, refer to the following:

ApplicationRole class

```
 public class ApplicationRole:IdentityRole
{
    public string Location { get; set; }//add the stuff you want
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser class

```
 public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public List<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Configure one-to-many relationship in the Fluent API

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.ApplicationRoles)
                .WithOne(r => r.ApplicationUser);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but my problem is i want to recognize my user with third attribute, that if my user have two roles in two diffrent companies and i want to delete company A, my user role destroyed in company A but not change in company B.

Comment: Do you mean that the user's role is determined by the third attribute added later? Is every company has some of same roles, but the same user has different roles in different companies ? If you could share the relevant code that you have tried , it will help us to provide more effective suggestions.

Comment: yes, we have many roles in our companies and one user can have diffrent role in each other. we want to identify our user by third attribute like companycode.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the roles table, there is an special table for these customization's called user-claims table. Here you can assign new and different attributes to users. roles are just another user-claims in ASP.NET Core Identity and will be translated to user-claims automatically behind the scene. Define a new user-claim (companyB, attrX), (companyA, attrZ). Then define a new Authorization Policy for it to use it.
Here are some official Docs about [user-claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far, because it actually refers to asp.net core features.